# Refrencing a CGRect Variable from a Different View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I need to refrence CGRect value in a different view Controller than the one it was created in for this function:

```
@IBAction func Pg5(sender: AnyObject) {

    let frame1: CGRect

    scrollRectToVisible(, animated: true)
}
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Post your actual code where you are calling this function. And also instantiation method to other viewController.

Comment: I've posted it. It will be super helpful if you can help me in my problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: `scrollRectToVisible(, animated: true)` does not have your CGRect set, who is sending data to this method?

Comment: This is my problem. I'm trying to set it but I need to know how to refrence it from a different view controller. Do you know how to do it?